# Is there anyway to find the logged in user is the same - Oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, oauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Oauth gem to login  to my web app with facebook, twitter and google accounts. For that I have created a project in each of them and got app id and secret id. I want a single entry in my database even the user logged in with the same mail id in all the three. We are storing the following info in database(email, name, provider, uid). The problem is twitter does not provide mail id. So I have planned to generate mail id from nick name.

user.rb

```
//for facebook and google
user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                        provider:auth.provider,
                        uid:auth.uid,
                        email:auth.info.email,
                        password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                      )

//for twitter
user = User.create(name: auth['info']['nickname'],
                        provider: auth.provider,
                        uid: auth.uid,
                        email: auth['info']['nickname'] + '@twitter.com',
                        password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                      )
```

For example

I log in with mail id example@gmail.com in facebook, twitter and google. But in my db it creates two entries

```
11 | example@gmail.com                // for facebook and google

12 | nickname@twitter.com             // for twitter
```

**I don't this behavior. Is it any other possible ways to find the logged in user is the same person?? I want just a single entry. Kindly suggest me any better ways if possible.**

Comment: how can you relate the twitter ID and the same user's gmail address?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not easily possible at present.  If there is no information in common between twitter and the other services, how can you automatically associate them?  Also, if you make up an `@twitter.com` email address for people logging in via twitter, then you've got an invalid/unusable email address in your database (unless that person is an employee of twitter and happens to have a twitter name the same as the local part of their email address - but worse, if someone happens to have a twitter name matching the local part of an email address of a twitter employee but isn't that employee, you've got a valid email address but the user on your site doesn't own it - I don't know if this is possible offhand, and if you are using :confirmable they wouldn't confirm the email address).

You've got at least a couple of options:

1. When the person has logged in via twitter and returns to your site, ask for their email address so you can check if they're already registered with that.
2. Generate some sort of fake unique email address for people coming from twitter that you can tell is fake later (so you never try to confirm it or send any other email to it) or allow blank email addresses (perhaps a bit tricky for devise because it's generally assumed that an email address is defined and exists for each user). Then allow people to merge arbitrary accounts on your site by logging in using one of them and then entering the credentials for the other one (the credentials would need to be them logging in via the external service, because they won't know your auto-generated Devise.friendly_token password unless the other account was one registered directly with your site, if you support that).  You then have to deal with merging whatever is associated with those two accounts, which might be tricky depending on what you have associated with a user in your model.

For a comprehensive system, you might want to allow people to merge arbitrary accounts anyway, for the situation where the same person is registered with different email addresses on google and Facebook for example.

Also, note that you won't necessarily get an email address back from Facebook for someone logging in via Facebook.  People can register with Facebook with just a phone number, so in that case Facebook doesn't have their email address.